# Unable to view File Shares

Tags: networking, windows-10, windows-server-2003, smb

I have a Windows 10 and Windows Server 2003 machines that both have file shares. Both are on the same Workgroup and the same user/password exists on both machines (local login, not domain).

Each server can ping the other server. I can also telnet on port 445 from 2003 to Win10.

From the 2003 server I can see the Win10 machine when I open up the workspace, but when I double click the machine, it can't connect.

Does this seem like a permissions issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMBv1 is not installed by default in Windows 10 1709, if you are using this version of Windows 10, you need to enable SMBv1 in Windows Features manually.

Considering Server 2003, you may need to disable SMBv2 and SMBv3.

About Permission issue, just ensure that you are using administrator accounts to login Windows 10  and Server 2003, note these two account have configured password. Meanwhile, share folder has configured correct permission for visitors.

Comment: Yes, the problem was that SMBv1 was disabled.